# Restoring correct line number with Keyword::Simple

Tags: perl, keyword, line-numbers

I'm using [Keyword::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Keyword%3a%3aSimple) to interface with the Perl keyword API to inject some custom code. Problem is, if my custom code has newlines in it, any errors in the code will be reported from the wrong line in the original file. For example:

```
# KWTest.pm

package KWTest;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Keyword::Simple;

sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    Keyword::Simple::define mydie => sub {
        my $ref = shift;
        substr $$ref, 0, 0, qq{\n\n\n\n\n die "oh noes!!!!"};
    };

}

1;
```

Then

```
perl -MKWTest -E 'mydie'
oh noes!!!! at -e line 6.
```

I know that `perl` will respect `#line` directives to change the reported line number, but in order to inject these in generated code I would need to know the pre-munged line number first.

I suppose I could also do it by just making sure my generated code contains no newlines, but that seems less fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is when you're parsing code, count how many line breaks you skip over, and then when you inject code, inject the same number of line breaks, and don't inject any unnecessary line breaks. It's a bit of work, but it [can be done](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Moops-0.031/t/03lines.t).

Comment: But how would I count the lines before my keyword appears?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.

Comment: PS: the relevant code for line number preservation in Moops::Parser can be found in [`_eat_space`](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Moops-0.031/lib/Moops/Parser.pm#L68) and [`parse`](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Moops-0.031/lib/Moops/Parser.pm#L235).

Comment: So the answer is just "don't insert newlines." OK. :)

Comment: Well, don't insert new lines, *unless* you remove any new lines, in which case try to insert exactly the same number of them.